# Design Pattern for Integrate External API Data with Existing Service Layer in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, jpa, design-patterns, clean-architecture

I have a Spring Boot application with a ProductService layer that interacts with a ProductRepository extending <ProductEntity, String.class>. Now, we're tasked with integrating an external API that provides product data similar to the ProductEntity parameters but in a smaller extent.
We've created an ExternalService class to handle HTTP calls using RestTemplate and returns an ExternalService response. This response needs to be mapped to a List in the controller layer. But in service getProducts() we need to check user access for external API, if no access just return product list from database.

Within the service layer, we have some filtering and processing logic (which is not applicable to external API calls, that is why,Proxy design pattern for data source layer is difficult) applied to List before finally mapping it to List for the controller layer.

How can I seamlessly integrate the data fetched from the external API with my existing service layer? What is the best design pattern we can use here, which be between controller and Service layer or between service layer and data access layer?
[image]